# Accessing global variables in a separate PHP script?

Tags: php, include, scope, global-variables

I'm trying to import some variables from a PHP script. It seems simple but I cannot get it to work.

The script contains some global variables like that:

```
$server_hostname = "localhost";
$server_database = "kimai";
$server_username = "root";
$server_password = "";
$server_conn     = "mysql";
$server_type     = "";
$server_prefix   = "kimai_";
$language        = "en";
$password_salt   = "7c0wFhYHHnK5hJsNI9Coo";
```

Then in my script, I would like to access these variables, so I've done:

```
require_once 'includes/autoconf.php';   
var_dump($server_hostname);
```

But this just outputs NULL. I've also tried:

```
require_once 'includes/autoconf.php';

global $server_hostname;    
var_dump($server_hostname);
```

but still not working.

I've added some `echo` statements in the "autoconf.php" file so I know that it's being loaded.

Any idea how I could access these variables?

Comment: If they are defined in a function then it will be private to that function. Even if you use global elsewhere

Comment: They are not in a function. The code I posted is the complete code.

Comment: do you have any other errors except that the variable does not seem to be in the namespace? activate the error output if the errors are hidden.

Comment: Check out PHP.ini file for global variable settings, im not sure if there is a setting but could be worth a look

Comment: have you tried using include_once("includes/autoconf.php"); ?

Comment: Do you check out if (file_exists('includes/autoconf.php')) require_once 'includes/autoconf.php';
else echo 'File not exists';
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the file was included somewhere else in the application so when I was calling `require_once`, the file was not being included at all. I changed it to just `require` and now it works.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define the variable as global first:

```
global $server_hostname;
$server_hostname = "localhost";
```

Comment: But anyway, I don't think that this is needed if you later on do a inlude or require, it should work just as you tried.

Comment: My understanding is that variables declared outside of any function or block are already in the global scope (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) Also I cannot modify this script directly so I need to access the variables some other way.

Comment: They are in the global scope but in other files or functions you need to add global $varname;

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the file was not included properly.

```
require_once 'includes/autoconf.php';
```

check current work directory where you include `autoconf.php`

try this

```
if (file_exists('includes/autoconf.php')) require_once 'includes/autoconf.php';
else echo 'File not exists';
```

to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a constant?

define("server_hostname","localhost");
define("server_hostname","localhost");

Comment: I cannot change the code in this autoconf.php file. Of course, if I could I'd simply avoid using any global variable at all.

Comment: TRUE but isn't this a constant, not variable

Comment: that is semantic anyway. The fact that a variable is not loaded, it means that the constant will not be loaded as well. Is a loading issue .

Answer (score 0):

If you include the file and the variable is in a plain text, and not inside a function / class it works without the global

Go to your php.ini and put display_errors=On and errors to E_ALL so you will see which is the correct reason

Answer (score 0):

This is evil, but it may get the job done.

```
<? //PHP 5.4+
\call_user_func(static function(){
    $globals = \get_defined_vars();
    include 'includes/autoconf.php';
    $newVars = \array_diff_key($globals, \get_defined_vars());
    foreach($newVars as $name => $value){
        \define($name, $value);
    }
});
//Variables defined in file are now constants!
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

better way to use and correct global variables is first assign value to variable and then declare global.
this is:

```
$server_hostname = "localhost";
global $server_hostname;
```